# Smartface iOS Emulator Error

Tags: mobile, smartface.io

I always get this `An error occurred during file transfer! Please check your USB connection and try again` error in smartface. I have read the iOS emulator troubleshooting documents but did not work. There is no any problem with my cable. Everyting is OK. who has any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It might occur about your iTunes installation.

Check the Itunes version and install the newest one.

Also, fake cables causes problems during file transfers.

Smartface.io Team